# How to delete a proactive message sent by notification only bot in Microsoft teams bot?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have created a notification only bot using bot framework and following the documentation in the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet

now, I want an option to delete a proactive notification sent by the bot. I looked into the following link but as far as I can tell, this is only for the conversation bot which creates turn context and activity Id.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet

I need to delete the notification sent to all the installed users. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be feasible. However, you can achieve a similar effect by following below steps: 1. When sending the proactive notification, keep track of the sent messages by storing their message IDs or conversation references.
2. To delete a proactive notification, use the `UpdateActivityAsync` method to update the original message with a deletion indicator. You can set the `text` property of the activity to a specific value (e.g., "This message has been deleted") or remove the content of the message.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT If UpdateActivityAsync is possible if I store the conversation reference. by same logic is DeleteActivityAsync feasible too ?

Comment: Did you get chance to try that out?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I tried it out. But saving only the conversation reference does not seem to be working. Any update or delete Request goes through Authentication and Authorization of JWT tokens normally generated by Teams when sending a request. I cannot emulate or bypass those steps. If you have done it before, can you post a skeleton code for me to follow ?

Answer (score 1):

1. When sending the proactive notification, keep track of the sent messages by storing their message IDs or conversation references.
2. To delete a proactive notification, use the UpdateActivityAsync method to update the original message with a deletion indicator. You can set the text property of the activity to a specific value (e.g., "This message has been deleted") or remove the content of the message.

   ```
   private async Task DeleteNotificationAsync(string messageId, string serviceUrl){
   var conversationReference = new ConversationReference
    {
        ServiceUrl = serviceUrl,
        Conversation = new ConversationAccount { Id = messageId }
    };
    var botAdapter = (BotFrameworkAdapter)_adapter;
    var botCallback = new BotCallbackHandler(BotCallback);
    await botAdapter.ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, botCallback, default(CancellationToken));
    // Update the original message with a deletion indicator
    var updatedMessage = new Activity
    {
        Id = messageId,
        Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
        Text = "This message has been deleted"
    };
    await botAdapter.UpdateActivityAsync(conversationReference, updatedMessage);}
   ```

Comment: I was able to even delete the notification sent using this methodology. Thanks.