# How to delete or update a previously send proactive message using a Teams bot?

Tags: botframework, proactive-message

I am working on a business requirement that involves the ability to update or delete proactive messages sent to Microsoft Teams using the Bot Framework. The update or deletion might occur long after the initial message was sent. I've come across a [similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77169634/how-to-delete-a-proactive-message-sent-by-notification-only-bot-in-microsoft-tea) that was answered with a sample code. However, when attempting to implement the provided solution, I encountered an obstacle related to the UpdateActivityAsync method's signature.

In the sample code, the method's signature differs from what is supported in my case. Specifically, the signature in my case requires an instance of ITurnContext as input, unlike the proposed signature in the sample code.

Here is the signature:

public override async Task UpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue. If anyone has experience with updating or deleting proactive messages in Teams using the Bot Framework, your insights would be invaluable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete or update a previously send proactive message using a Teams bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749520/how-to-delete-or-update-a-previously-send-proactive-message-using-a-teams-bot)